# How to create web services client with apache cxf?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2011/09/create-cxf-client) to create a client. 
Is this valid code to make a request to another web service deployed on the same server ?
Could not find any relevant documentation or example :(

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

factory.setServiceClass(ChangeStudentDetails.class);
factory.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/CXFTutorial/ChangeStudent?wsdl");

factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

ChangeStudentDetails studenClient = (ChangeStudentDetails) factory.create();
studenClient.setName("Rockey");

// Is this valid code ?
factory.setAddress("http://localhost:8080/CXFTutorial/ChangeTeacher?wsdl");
ChangeTeacherDetails teacherClient = (ChangeTeacherDetails) factory.create();
Teacher teacher = teacherClient.setName("Leonardo");
```

Comment: Yes, why not? You can also look at JAXRSClientFactory of cxf-rt-rs-client

Comment: @pmartin8 Thanks, by the way i am trying to consume  soap service

Answer (score 1):

The following source has several working examples:

https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/master/services/sts/systests/advanced/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/sts/caching/CachingTest.java#L107

```
    SpringBusFactory bf = new SpringBusFactory();
    URL busFile = CachingTest.class.getResource("cxf-client.xml");

    Bus bus = bf.createBus(busFile.toString());
    SpringBusFactory.setDefaultBus(bus);
    SpringBusFactory.setThreadDefaultBus(bus);

    URL wsdl = CachingTest.class.getResource("DoubleIt.wsdl");
    Service service = Service.create(wsdl, SERVICE_QNAME);
    QName portQName = new QName(NAMESPACE, "DoubleItTransportSAML1Port");
    DoubleItPortType port = 
        service.getPort(portQName, DoubleItPortType.class);
    ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put("thread.local.request.context", "true");
    updateAddressPort(port, PORT);

    // Make a successful invocation
    doubleIt(port, 25);

    // Change the STSClient so that it can no longer find the STS
    BindingProvider p = (BindingProvider)port;
    clearSTSClient(p, bus);

    // This should succeed as the token is cached
    doubleIt(port, 30);

    // This should fail as the cached token is manually removed
    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
    Endpoint ep = client.getEndpoint();
    ep.remove(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_ID);
    ep.remove(SecurityConstants.TOKEN);

    try {
        doubleIt(port, 35);
        fail("Expected failure on clearing the cache");
    } catch (SOAPFaultException ex) {
        // Expected
    }

    ((java.io.Closeable)port).close();
    bus.shutdown(true);
```

Comment: can you add link to the documentation to used library and its documentation

Answer (score 0):

This might be relevant:

```
public void useWebClient() {
    System.out.println("Using WebClient to get the book with id 123");
    WebClient client = WebClient.create("http://localhost:" + port + "/services/bookstore/");
    Book book = client.post(new Book("HTTP"), Book.class);
    System.out.println(book.getId() + ":" + book.getName());
}

public void useJMSClient() throws Exception {

    System.out.println("Getting the book with id 123 over JMS");

    getBookOverJMS();

    System.out.println("Adding a new book over JMS");
    addGetBookOverJMS(new Book("JMS Transport"));

    System.out.println("Adding a new book over JMS Oneway");
    addGetOnewayBookOverJMS();

    System.out.println("Adding a new book over HTTP Oneway, " 
            + " and getting it back over JMS");
    addOnewayOverHttpGetOverJMS();
}
```

Full source code:

http://code.openhub.net/file?fid=0fBMqrwxmzdpDR3J4W1NvMxLnbA&cid=rtwtj2OYF4c&s=How%20to%20create%20web%20services%20client%20with%20apache%20cxf%3F&pp=0&fl=Java&ff=1&filterChecked=true&fp=1511&mp,=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&projSelected=true#L0

Comment: can you tell me why the above stated code is better ?